# Tips on dealing with difficult professors?

Tags: university, professorship, undergraduate

I'm planning on going back to college (university for those folks across the 
pond) and I was wondering what are some things that you have done to deal 
with difficult professors. I had a C++ class when I was attending a couple 
years ago and the professor pretty much abandoned me and (I suspect) graded 
with bias against me. Sometime during the semester this professor came to the conclusion 
that I wasn't proper CS major material, so  refused to answer any questions 
that I had about the coursework and flunked me on all my projects, blaming me 
for plagiarism (which is entirely untrue and unproven since the university 
uses a fairly comprehensive program to determine if students are 
plagiarizing). Needless to say, I finished the semester with under a 20% in 
that class and failed all but the first program (studying my A-- off for the 
whole semester). Now that I'm looking to go back, I don't want to have this 
happen again because tuition is expensive as heck and it's taken me two years 
just to save up for one year's tuition.

Just as a side note, I am an active participant in class, polite, and 
non-disruptive.

Comment: By "go back" you mean going back to the same professor? And also, how did you do with the other professors?

Comment: I'll be attending the same university and will have to repeat the class but I won't have to deal with that same professor (apparently she was fired a year after I left). I did well with other professors and no other issues to speak of.  I just don't want to get caught with my pants down again.

Comment: Well... then I'd suggest ask the question when you're in trouble again. You didn't really explain why she hated you with so much passion; and there are many types of craziness. It's hard to give you a remotely useful response. If you believe you're acting with respect and integrity, then go on and don't expect everyone to like you. Also, chat with other students who had taken the course to get a sense of the teachers and styles may help. Good luck!

Comment: Honestly I have no idea why she acted the way she did. I did run into another student she failed in my calc class that semester who was extremely knowledgeable and helped me with the questions that my professor refused to answer. I know it's a pretty broad question, but thanks for your input.

Comment: Questions concerning problems faced by undergraduate students are off-topic on this site, hence my down vote.

Comment: Then where would you suggest posting any future questions?

Comment: @Jigg graduate students may also have to deal with difficult professors, so this question applies to them as well. It is therefore *not* an "undergraduate question"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing you need to understand is that your perspective is different from that of the teacher. You see one teacher but the teacher sees hundreds of students.

**While you may think that your participation is class is helpful, it might not be.** I have had students who were very eager to participate in class but kept participating in wrong or inappropriate ways. Not extremely wrong but just enough to actually draw the class's attention away from the points I was trying to make. Yes, students should participate but make sure you are actually helping and not hindering the teacher's efforts.

If you see you are having a problem with one specific teacher and not others, then **schedule some time during office hours** and have a one-on-one talk with the teacher. You both have the same goal: For you to learn. So, find out what the problem is. I have not found many teachers who are simply unreasonable all the time. Talk with them and understand their reasoning.

One last point, which is connected to meeting the teacher, is to find out what extra material you should be studying and actually study it and discuss it with the teacher, in class or after class. **Show that you are a serious student and the teacher will usually respect you.**

Comment: +1 on this, and going to office hours for help, asking relevant questions about assignments (not stuff that can be found on the internet within 20 seconds of searching), discussing works in progress, etc. should also help avoid any "plagiarism" issues - being clever and tricking some sort of plagiarism detection software isn't hard, being able to talk about an explain the concepts is much more important